# Updating the DOM with data from a table in my Rails app

Tags: javascript, sql, ruby-on-rails, dom, activerecord

I am creating a travel site that allows users to create itineraries. There are a number of places they can choose from in the area and if they like a place, they may add it to their itinerary by clicking a link which runs an add_place action in the itinerary controller.  This simply records the user_id of current_user and the place_id of the place they clicked so that users and their places can be matched.  Now that this works, I want to query the database for the name values on the itinerary table and return all of them to the DOM as a list, which is on a separate page.  I am unfamiliar with how to do this and I could really use help.

ERB for the place to be added:

```
<div class = "places_container">
    <h3 class = "places_subheader">Slice Pizza</h3>
        <div class = "slice_pic places"></div>
        <p class = "place_description">
            Slice specializes in Trenton-style pizza pies made with organic ingredients.  They offer a wide selection of pies, with a range of organic, gluten-free, vegan, and hormone-free ingredients. 
        </p>
        <%= link_to "Add to My Itinerary", "/add_place/2" %>
</div>
```

The Itineraries Controller:

```
class ItinerariesController < ApplicationController
    def add_place
        # current_user
        @place = Place.find(params[:id])
        @itenerary = @place.itineraries.create(user_id: current_user.id)

        redirect_to pizza_path
    end
end
```

The Schema for Itineraries and Places:

```
  create_table "itineraries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "place_id"
  end

  create_table "places", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "latitude"
    t.decimal  "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: That list is on a "separate page", but should be automatically be updated? If so you could use a peridodic ajax updater. If not you just have to display it in your usual page.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be automatically updated, because items can be intermittently added and deleted from the list.